# Android top pagination

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with linear layout manager. There 3 items loaded, current position after first position. I add custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener and when i scroll down, it loads more item

```
adapter.updateDays(weeksList.subList(currentItem, items.size()));
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(currentItem, currentItem + (items.size() - currentItem));
```

and i updating in my adapter class list, i don't have problems with down scroll

but, if I scroll up, I use

```
adapter.updateTopDays(list.subList(0, 5));
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, 5);
```

and in my adapter class, i update

```
this.items.addAll(0,list);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

that method cause strange behavior, like some items dissapeared, lagging, how can i fix this?

Comment: how did you solve this issue , i am facing something similar while building a chat module , as i scroll up for previous chats and add the list at 0th position the adapter gets messed up and some of the messages are displayed as sent by the receiver while they have been sent by the user .

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat oh, I was playing with addOnScrollListener with top pagination and found some solution. I can send to you code of my scrollListener, if you prove email or something else